# How to generate instance of bounded variable type?

Tags: java

Can this generate an instance of an object ?

```
 public <?> getDAO ( Class<?>DAO){

      //if using this DAO class is permitted or DAO class exists
    //we have HashMap map
return map.get(DAO);

}
```

or maybe it's

```
public <T> T getDAO ( <T extends AGenericDAO> DAO){ // GenericDAO<E,I>

          //if using this DAO class is permitted or DAO class exists
        //we have HashMap map
    return map.get(DAO);

    }
```

?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is:

```
public <T extends AGenericDAO> T getDAO(final Class<T> daoClass) {
    return daoClass.cast(map.get(daoClass));
}
```

where `map` has type `java.util.Map<Class<? extends AGenericDAO>, AGenericDAO>`.